# How to change the template engine in Pyramid?

Tags: python, pyramid, template-engine, mustache

In particular I want to use [pystache](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystache) but any guide for another template engine should be good enough to set it up.

If I understood correctly, I have to register the renderer factory in the `__init__.py` of my pyramid application.

```
config = Configurator(settings=settings)
config.add_renderer(None, 'pystache_renderer_factory')
```

Now I need to create the renderer factory and don't know how.

Even though I found [the documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.0-branch/narr/renderers.html#adding-and-changing-renderers) about how to add a template engine, I didn't manage to set it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I was able to add the pystache template engine following this guide:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/pylons-discuss/add_renderer/pylons-discuss/Y4MoKwWKiUA/cyqldA-vHjkJ

What I did:

created the file mustacherenderer.py:

```
from pyramid.asset import abspath_from_asset_spec 
import pystache
import os 

def pystache_renderer_factory(info):
    template = os.path.join(abspath_from_asset_spec('myproj:templates', False),
                            info.name)
    f = open(template) 
    s = f.read() 
    f.close() 
    def _render(value, system):
        return pystache.render(s, value)
    return _render
```

added this to the `__init__.py`:

```
config.add_renderer('.pmt', 'myproj.mustacherenderer.pystache_renderer_factory')
```

working :)

Answer (score 2):

`add_renderer`'s second argument is supposed to be a class that implements the interface shown in "Adding a New Renderer". Pyramid will take `pystache_renderer_factory` and attempt to import it, so in your code the line `import pystache_renderer_factory` would have to work. This example won't ever resolve to a class, only a module or package, so you'll have to fix that first. It should be something like `mypackage.pystache_renderer_factory`.

The best way to learn how to write a renderer is probably to look at some that have been written already. Specifically the `pyramid_jinja2` package, or in Pyramid's source there are very simple implementations of `json` and `jsonp` renderers. Notice how they all provide fairly unique ways to implement the required interface. Each factory accepts an `info` object, and returns a callable that accepts `value` and `system` objects.

[https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/master/pyramid_jinja2/**init**.py#L260](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/blob/master/pyramid_jinja2/__init__.py#L260)

https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/renderers.py#L135

Comment: thx for your answer. I looked in the source code already, hoped there is more of a step-by-step guide (as I'm new to python and pyramid). found a simple guide shortly after I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8171941) works well until you create your Pyramid project with a scaffold.  Once you do so, this related answer will prove more useful when constructing your Pystache/Mustache_Renderer_Factory: [How to integrate pystache with pyramid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10857206).