# How to integrate pystache with pyramid?

Tags: python, template-engine, pyramid, mustache

I would like to use the class based views that pystache offers in my pyramid application, but I'm not entirely sure how to integrate the two properly. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169606/how-to-change-the-template-engine-in-pyramid) already, but it doesn't talk about using the class based views.

How would I create a new renderer for pystache if I wanted to use class based views? Can somebody help me out here?

Also, while I already know how mustache works, I can't seem to find much information on the python implementation (pystache). Can somebody point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a `MustacheRendererFactory`:

```
class MustacheRendererFactory(object):
  def __init__(self, info):
    self.info = info

  def __call__(self, value, system):
    package, filename = resolve_asset_spec(self.info.name)
    template = os.path.join(package_path(self.info.package), filename)
    template_fh = open(template)
    template_stream = template_fh.read()
    template_fh.close()
    return pystache.render(template_stream, value)
```

Update your configurator setup, probably in `__init__.py`:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
  config = Configurator(settings=settings)
  # ...
  # Use Mustache renderer
  config.add_renderer(name='.mustache',
    factory='myapp.mustacherenderer.MustacheRendererFactory')
  # ...
```

Use in your views:

```
@view_config(route_name='myview', renderer='myapp:templates/notes.mustache')
def my_view(request):
  # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In pyramid, the renderer view argument is a string, it can't be a class. Thus, there is no way to just say

```
@view_config(route_name='someroute', renderer=MyClassBasedView)
```

The easiest solution might be to call the renderer manually.

```
return Response(pystache.render(ViewClass))
```

If you really want to use the pyramid renderer system, you can use a fake renderer string of the form "dotted path to class + extension". The renderer factory would then resolve the dotted path to get the class and return the renderer.

I must say I'm not sure I understand how you would use pystache class based views in pyramid. Defining class with methods that return values seems more complicated than returning a dict, and computing the values in those methods instead of doing it in the pyramid views might lead to more cluttered code. The inheritance might have some advantages I haven't considered, though.

---

As for pystache, the documentation seems limited to the [pypi page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pystache), but [the code](https://github.com/defunkt/pystache) is clean and easy to read (I skimmed through it before answering the question).

Comment: Mustache templates do a great job in slimming down controllers and cleaning up templates. Working with mustache in PHP, I've learned to love it...

Comment: I'm using class based views... Is there any way to allow rendering of the page to be done by the base controller desctructor? Or MUST each view return a response?

Comment: Something like `def home(self): self.view.set(foo=bar)` `def render(self): return Response(self.view.render())` and setup some type of event system to call render

Comment: Pyramid views are nothing more than callable that return a Response. If you want complex behaviour, you can always implement it yourself.