# What would a Cheetah template binding for Pyramid look like?

Tags: python, pyramid, cheetah

I've found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169606/how-to-change-the-template-engine-in-pyramid), which talks about Pystache, and I've seen a few bindings on Github for other engines but I'm confused on how to get Cheetah to work with Pyramid. Any pointers or what the code might look like?

Comment: Have you looked at the existing [documentation](http://pyramid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/narr/renderers.html#adding-and-changing-renderers) and implementations for [Chameleon (ZPT version)](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/chameleon_zpt.py), [Mako](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/blob/master/pyramid/mako_templating.py) and [Jinja2](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jinja2/tree/master/pyramid_jinja2)?